# Can I sent the same OTP in SMS and in Email using twilio verify?

Tags: twilio, verify, twilio-verify

We want to provide an option to end user so that the user can get 2FA code in both way(in email and in SMS at same time)? Is it possible to send the same OTP via email as well as SMS at same time in verify?

I tryed with single verification channel its working.i want same otp in email as well as SMS using Twilio Verify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you need to specify a single channel.

PS: My personal take it that this is also the better UX as it avoids confusion.